Differential equation problem and Taylor series
Consider the following differential equation:
$\frac{dy}{dx}=\epsilon y^2$
$y(0)=1$
Find the first two terms in the approximation to the solution $y\approx{y_0+\epsilon y_1}$.
I really struggle with Taylor expansion and am unsure and how to solve this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What do you mean by $y0$ ?

Try to plug $y0+ey1$ in the equation

Let us write $y = y_0 + \epsilon y_1$:
$$y_0'+\epsilon y_1'(x) = y'(x) = \epsilon y(x)^2=\epsilon y_0(x)^2 + 2\epsilon^2y_0(x)y_1(x) + \epsilon^3y_1(x)^2.$$
Equating each term in front of $\epsilon$, we get:
$$y_0'(x)=0.$$
Thus $y_0(x)=1$ (due to the initial condition $y(0)=1$). Next, we have in front of $\epsilon$:
$$y_1'(x)=y_0(x)=1.$$
Thus $y_1(x)=x$ and we get the following approximation:
$$y(x)\sim1+\epsilon x.$$

In this situation, the equation can be analytically solved:
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{1-\epsilon x}\qquad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\Big\{\frac{1}{\epsilon}\Big\}.$$
In the limit $\epsilon x\to0$ (for example if $x$ is fixed and $\epsilon\to0$), we of course have:
$$y(x)=1+\epsilon x+\mathcal{O}_{\epsilon\to0}(\epsilon^2x^2).$$

I don't think this is a good example to practice or implement a perturbation/Taylor expansion method on. As shown by @Nicholas, you can obtain a regular perturbation $y \sim 1+\varepsilon x $; however, this is not uniformly valid when $x=\mathcal{O}(1/\varepsilon)$ as the series is no longer asymptotic (both terms are of equal order).
You can just scale $x=\bar{x}/\varepsilon$ and then solve the ODE $y'(\bar{x})=y^2$, and upon re-scaling the solution you obtain the analytical solution. Your perturbation series $y \sim 1+\varepsilon x $ suggests that this scaling is necessary anyway as you need to obtain a solution for $x=\mathcal{O}(1/\varepsilon).$

"I really struggle with Taylor expansion"
Taking into account the boundary condition, write
$$y=1+a_1x+a_2x^2$$ Put everything on the same side and expand to obtain
$$(a_1-\epsilon )+2(a_2-a_1 \epsilon )x-\left(a_1^2+2 a_2\right)  \epsilon x^2-2 a_1 a_2 \epsilon x^3-a_2^2  \epsilon x^4 =0$$ So, $a_1= \epsilon$ and $a_2=\epsilon^2$
